# Is there a way to include records in an interaction that do not have an email address?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In an interaction is it possible to have records that do not have an email address?

And if so, how is this done?

What I have found is that records with email address are used as people in the interaction and records without do not enter the interaction.

Comment: What would be the use case and scenario where there would not be an email address and you would need them to enter an interaction?  What activities are you using in the (JB) Interaction?  Only valid "Contacts" can enter an Interaction setup within JourneyBuilder.  What is your One-to-One Relationship setup in Contact Builder to where you would not have an email address pulling back for the contact?

Comment: For where no email - is it possible to add/config channels other than email, ott, push or sms?

Comment: Yes, JourneyBuilder does have the ability to work with MobilePush or MobileConnect.  You may need to speak with your Account Executive at SF Marketing Cloud for further info and setup if needed.  Info on the different canvas activities:  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/